# How to handle Spark Executors when number of partitions do not match no of Executors?

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have 3 executors and 4 partitions, and we assume theses number cannot be changed.

This is not an efficient setup, because we have to read 2 passes: in 1 pass, we read 3 partitions; and in the second partition, we read 1 partition.

Is there a way in Spark that we can improve the efficiency without changing the number of executors and partitions?

Comment: I never understand why a -1 is given for this type of question as they are good ones imho. However, do you mean 4 partitions from reading an HDFS source or 4 partitions are repartitioining an RDD, for an example. Or a DS or DF?

Comment: @thebluephantom I cannot agree with you here. OP requirements pretty much say "don't change anything" so the only reasonable answer is to accept the facts and move on. Furthermore the problem is not well defined. If performance is understood as a single job latency then not much can be done, given the restrictions (ditto), but it is definitely not an universal definition of efficiency.

Comment: @user6910411  Not sure I totally follow. Problem not well defined, indeed, but that's why I asked. That said, it is not well explained some of the aspects. I work with persons not understanding any of this, so good that some people ask... surely?

Comment: @thebluephantom I mean - the downvote button says "This question (...) is unclear (...)" and you said yourself it is not clear, so while I only casted close-vote, downvote would be justified.

Comment: cool, but I note a lot of people are unclear on exactly this question type. I am also looking at this aspect as I grow on the SPARK side alongside companion objects (bah) and serialization. You could embellish it and reduce the ignorance out there ... More importantly is the answer good iyo?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you need to update the number of cores.

In spark each partition is taken up for execution by one task of spark. As you have 3 executors and 4 partitions and if you assume you have total 3 cores I.e one core per executor then 3 partition of data will be run in parallel and one partition will be taken once one core for the executor will be free. To handle this latency we need to increase spark.executor.cores=2. I.e each executor can run 2 threads at a time I.e 2 tasks at a time.

So all your partitions will be executed in parallel but it does not guarantee whether 1 executor will run 2 tasks and 2 executors will run one task each or 2 executors will run 2 tasks on 2 individual partitions with one executor will be idle.